# Set Undefined to BIT values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a column `isWantedBack` for an Employee with BIT as data type.
If it is 1 if the employee leaves,  he can be rehired
If it is 0 it's the opposite.
As I am trying to clean the data, I want to accord -1 to records having `isWantedBack` as `NULL`

When I try to do so :

```
SELECT ISNULL(EC.isWantedBack,-1) AS isWantedBack ...
```

I get 1 instead of -1 as result

Comment: Read the [manual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/bit-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15); "An integer data type that can take a value of 1, 0, or NULL."

Comment: If you want to store the values `1`, `0`, `-1`, and `NULL` then `bit` is the wrong data type choice. The smallest integer type that can store those datatypes is a `smallint` (`tinyint`is unsigned, so can only store `0`-`255`). You'd probably be better off with a `decimal(1,0)` with can store the values `-9`-`9`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`ISNULL(check_expression, replacement_value)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnull-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) returns *the same type as check_expression* which in your case is `BIT` and this is why you get `1` instead of `-1`.
Instead, if you want the resut as an integer in the `SELECT` statement, use [`COALESCE(expression \[ ,...n \])`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql?view=sql-se) which returns *the data type of expression with the highest data type precedence* and since `BIT` has [lower precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) than any integer data type, you will get `-1` as result:

```
SELECT COALESCE(EC.isWantedBack,-1) AS isWantedBack
```

You could also achieve the same with a `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN EC.isWantedBack IS NULL THEN -1 ELSE isWantedBack END AS isWantedBack
```

See a simplified [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=03fad1d2efe1cefb0248b0890730e970).